# How is the total_gain method of get_score in the XGBoost model calculated mathematically?

Tags: python, xgboost

Here is my code and the visualization of my tree

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import graphviz
import os

sample_num = 10
feature_num = 2

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randn(sample_num, feature_num)
np.random.seed(0)
label = np.random.randint(0, 2, sample_num)
train_data = xgb.DMatrix(data, label=label,feature_names=["A","B"])
params = {'max_depth': 3}
bst = xgb.train(params, train_data,1)
print('total_gain:',bst.get_score(importance_type='total_gain'))
```

The generated data is:

```
array([[1.76405235,0.40015721],
[0.97873798,2.2408932],
[1.86755799,-0.97727788],
[0.95008842,-0.15135721],
[-0.10321885,0.4105985 ],
[0.14404357,1.45427351],
[0.76103773,0.12167502],
[0.44386323,0.33367433],
[1.49407907,-0.20515826],
[0.3130677 ,-0.85409574]
])
```

and label:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Here is the final generated tree:
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2kDj.png)

result is:

```
total_gain: {'A': 0.265151441, 'B': 0.75000003}
```

Please tell me how these results are calculated. It would be even better if you could provide the
formulas. Thank you very much.